# Алгоритмы поиска ближайшего вектора

Tags: алгоритм, поисковая-оптимизация

Дан список векторов с размерностью больше двух, нам на вход подается произвольный вектор, требуется найти из списка векторов наиболее близкий(в качестве меры близости расстояние левенштейна),но без полного прохода по списку. Я знаю несколько алгоритмов поиска ближайших соседей ,которые позволяют найти ближайший похожий элемент: кd-деревья, диаграммы вороного, но они направлены на поиск элементов в плоскости или  в 3-мерном пространстве. Есть ли такие же алгоритмы, только для поиска ближайшего вектора?

Comment: Что такое "ближайший вектор", известно только Вам.

Comment: Igor, ну например: 10001 и 10000- похожие, 101111 и 000000- непохожие

Comment: Какова размерность ваших векторов?

Comment: AnT , это имеет значение?

Comment: "10001 и 10000- похожие, 101111 и 000000- непохожие" - это больше похоже на расстояние Левенштейна...

Comment: Вектор - это направление и длина. Как только Вы сможете сравнить направление с длиной, Ваша задача будет решена.

Comment: AnT, да именно, но дело в том что я не хочу пробегаться по всем векторам

Comment: Вообще говоря да, это имеет значение. Если речь бы шла о двумерных векторах и "обычных" расстояниях, тогда было бы неясно, чем вас не устраивают классические структуры, которые вы сами уже назвали. А вам, оказывается, как будто нужно что-то иное. Правда действительно ли вам нужно иное - пока уверенности нет.

Comment: AnT, размерность больше двух, и нужно найти ближайший вектор(в качестве меры- расстояние левенштейна), но при этом не пробегаться по всем векторам списка

Comment: я мог бы использовать алгоритмы снижения рамерности чтобы перевести свои многомерные вектора в двумерную плоскость, и потом уже использовать алгоритмы которые я перечислил, но я бы хотел избежать этих преобразований

Comment: [How do I use kd-trees for determining string similarity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696859/how-do-i-use-kd-trees-for-determining-string-similarity).  Ещё ищите `BK-tree`.

Comment: [BK-tree](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees) во всей красе. То что вам надо.